# Unable to Access Spring Boot Application Metrics via Prometheus Actuator/Prometheus Interface

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

My spring app is deployed on k8s
I installed Prometheus to monitor it using

```
helm install prometheus prometheus-community/prometheus
```

in targets app is showing with STATE UP

my app service is

```
spring-consumer-service               LoadBalancer   1x.9x.xx.X7     localhost     8087:30001/TCP   22d
```

the prometheues configMap is

```
  prometheus.yml: |
    global:
      scrape_interval: 15s
      evaluation_interval: 15s
    scrape_configs:
      - job_name: 'spring'
        metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
        scrape_interval: 15s
        static_configs:
          - targets: ['1x.9x.8x.2xx:8087']
```

and I added the needed dependencies and the application.proprties lines

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true
```

```
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
                <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
```

Who can tell me what Im doing wrong  ?